# Why can't I select Springboot 2.1.1 not on Spring Tool Suite nor on https://start.spring.io/?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

This is my first project with **Springboot**.

I've been told to create a web application with **Springboot 2.1.1**.
This version is not available, not on **Spring Tool Suite 4** nor on **https://start.spring.io/**.

Since this is my first project with Springboot, and I miss a lot of knowledge about it, can you explain what's the issue about the version, and why 2.1.1 is missing?

I suppose Springboot version are related with the version of the inclided dependencies.

Thank you guys

Answer (score 1):

It has been already replaced with 2.1.2, when the minor numbers are updated (here the **x.x.2**) you can't select the previous ones in spring initializr.

So you want to select the 2.1.2 which is the same that the 2.1.1 with minor fixes.

Comment: No problem, enjoy spring boot :)